# Cleaner way of using inheritance to separate 'static' code from 'dynamic' code

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

(With static and dynamic I mean the distinction whether code is susceptible to change)

I have a bit of a weird problem I'm currently stuck on. I'm writing an application which involves some complex interactions between components in which it becomes hard to keep track of the code flow. To simplify this, I'm trying to structure the code by creating 'layers', where each layer has increased functionality compared to the layer above it. Each layer is contained in a package. I'm having the following problem:

Consider the following 2 classes and their subclasses with increased functionality:

Class A:

```
package layer;
class A {
    B b;

    A() {
        b = new B();
    }

    void foo() {
        b.foo();
    }

    /* More A-class methods here */
}
```

Class B:

```
package layer;
class B {
    void foo() {
        // Do something
    }

    /* More B-class methods here */
}
```

Subclass A:

```
package sublayer;
class ASub extends A {

    ASub() {
        super.b = new BSub(); // This needs a cast to compile
    }
}
```

Subclass B:

```
package sublayer;
class BSub extends B {
     @Override
     void foo() {
        // Do something with more functionality
     }
}
```

In the end I just want to instantiate and modify classes ASub and BSub, being able to use all methods of superclasses A and B without actually needing to modify code in classes A and B itself.

If I call `new ASub().foo()`, I want the overridden foo() of BSub to execute instead of that of B. Ofcourse I can add a variable `BSub bsub` in ASub and override A's foo() method to call `bsub.foo()`, but this doesnt avoid the creation of the object `b` in the constructor of A, which seems sloppy coding. Any thoughts on this? Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit controversial.  Object creation and dependency injection is the subject of a lot of discussion and a core focus of various frameworks and design patterns.

But here is, I hope, one simple answer to your question, which *isn't* a general "what's the best way to create objects in Java?"

In the code below, I move the responsibility of instantiating `B` to a method (`instantiateB()`) which is called from the `A` (superclass) constructor.  So, when you want to subclass `A`, you override that method instead of overriding the constructor.

```
package com.matt.tester;

public class SE {

    static class A {
        B b;

        A() {
            instantiateB();
        }

        void instantiateB () {
            this.b = new B();
        }

        void foo() {
            b.foo();
        }

        /* More A-class methods here */
    }

    static class B {
        void foo() {
            System.out.println("Hellow from B.foo()!");
        }

        /* More B-class methods here */
    }
    static class ASub extends A {

        @Override
        void instantiateB() {
            this.b = new BSub();
        }
    }
    static class BSub extends B {
         @Override
         void foo() {
            System.out.println("Hellow from BSub.foo()!");
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new ASub();
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will probably try this if there is no other way. It feels a bit like a hack, although it doesn't look too ugly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using inheritance to promote reusability is a really really bad idea. The inheritance should be always driven by the nature of the objects that you are trying to describe. You need to learn yourself to work with terms and abstractions to ask yourself "What is the nature of what I am trying to describe". My suggestion is to learn a book on Domain Driven Design for example or Code Complete. Also think about polymorphism and design patterns.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and thought about this. I'm not too sure why it's bad, but I guess my core problem is that I'm searching for a way to split my application in a 'base functionality' and on top of that more detailed additions. Thanks for your answer anyways

Comment: Use services, use helper classes use other patterns. Dont do inheritance only for the purpose of reusability Use aggregation instead. Think objects and encapsulation. If you want to make your will probably you will include your family and only rarely you will include someone else , same is with the programming. If we have a bad relative we can ignore him from the will , the same goes for subclasses with aucward logic. For example Map and MultiMap most implementations dont inherit from the same interface for Map and MultiMap even though essentially both are maps. Just the second one is awkward.